# how to get rows with null values and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Interviewer asked me the following question:

consider the below table :

```
tpid data
100 1
100 2
100 NULL
101 6
101 5
101 NULL
102 NULL
103 9
103 65
104 NULL
..
..
```

If the `tpid` has got any data then display the data and not null value
but if the `tpid` has got only null then only display null against the id.

The result set should be like this :

```
tpid data
100 1
100 2
101 6
101 5
102 NULL
103 9
103 65
104 NULL
```

I wrote the following query but it doesn't give the desired result :

```
;with cte as
(select tpid,count(data) as num from a group by TPID)

 select a.TPID,
 (case when cte.num=0 then NULL else a.DATA end)col
 from cte
join A on a.TPID=cte.TPID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use windowed functions to get what you want:

```
SELECT tpid, data
FROM (
  SELECT tpid, data,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tpid) AS cnt,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [data] IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY tpid) AS cntNulls
  FROM mytable) AS t
  WHERE (data IS NOT NULL) OR (cnt = cntNulls)
```

`NULL` values are filtered out, *unless* there is nothing but `NULL` values in a `tpid` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ccb37/3)

Alternatively you can use the following query:

```
SELECT t1.tpid, t1.data
FROM mytable AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT tpid
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY tpid
  HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN data IS NULL THEN 1 END)
) AS t2 ON t1.tpid = t2.tpid
WHERE (t1.data IS NOT NULL) OR (t2.tpid IS NOT NULL)
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ccb37/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(tpid int, data int)

INSERT INTO @temp 
SELECT 100, 1 UNION
SELECT 100, 2UNION
SELECT 100, NULL UNION
SELECT 101, 6 UNION
SELECT 101, 5 UNION
SELECT 101, NULL UNION
SELECT 102, NULL UNION
SELECT 103, 9 UNION
SELECT 103, 65 UNION
SELECT 104, NULL




SELECT * FROM @temp a WHERE 
data IS not NULL OR (select COUNT(1) FROM @temp WHERE tpid=a.tpid)=1
```

Ans:

```
tpid    data
100     1
100     2
101     5
101     6
102    NULL
103     9
103    65
104   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select tpid,data from (SELECT tpid, data,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tpid) AS cnt,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN [data] IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
         OVER (PARTITION BY tpid) AS cntNulls
  FROM mytable) t
  where t.cntNulls = t.cnt or data is not null
```

Comment: This looks like a copy/paste of my answer